# Get maximum value of each id in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have data like this

[image]

and I need output like this

[image]

Comment: use `max` window function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby everything and find max value. Code below

```
  from pyspark.sql import Window

df.withColumn('Value',max('Amount').over(Window.partitionBy())).show()
```

Comment: what is the difference between coding this way and using max and group by?